# How do i fix an bus error in c in this program with dynamic-memory-allocation?

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, bus-error

Why am i receiving a bus error?

I´m making a simple program that abbreviate the middle names, for example, we have Artur José Bastos Costa and it should print “Artur J. B. Costa”.

Here is my code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPOV5.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdFth.jpg)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* abrevia(char full_name[]){
    int numNames = 0, i = 0;
    char* abbreviation = (char*) malloc(strlen(full_name) * sizeof(char));
    char* name = strtok(full_name, " ");
    strcpy(abbreviation, name);
    strncat(abbreviation, " ", 1);
    while (name != NULL){
        numNames++;
        name = strtok(NULL, " "); 
    }

    char* nomeCopy = (char*) malloc(strlen(full_name) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(nomeCopy, full_name);
    char* name2 = strtok(nomeCopy, " ");
    while (name2 != NULL){
        if (i != numNames -1){
            strncat(abbreviation, &name2[0], 1);
            abbreviation[strlen(abbreviation)] = '.';
            abbreviation[strlen(abbreviation)] = ' ';
        }
        else {
            strcat(abbreviation, name2);
        }
        name2 = strtok(NULL, " ");
        i++;
    }
    free(nomeCopy);
    return abbreviation;
}

int main(){
    char* abr = abrevia("Artur José Bastos Costa");
    printf("%s", abr);
    free(abr);
    return 0;
}
```

First i didn´t copied the full_name, but i tried doing that becausa i was using strtok twice and there wasn´t more tokens in the first time, so i tought that in the second loop it will crash because of that. But i couldnt fix it.
Sorry my english is not my first language

Comment: `nomeCopy = (char*) malloc(strlen(full_name) * sizeof(char));` that's one too few, don't forget the terminating zero char

Comment: After `abbreviation[strlen(abbreviation)] = '.';` abbreviation is no longer null-terminated (you have overwritten the terminating char) and subsequent `strlen(abbreviation)` behavior is undefined. Use str(n)cat instead.

Comment: Reformatted code for readability.  Don't cast `void *`. sizeof(char) is defined as 1.

Comment: Prefer `for` over `while` loops for iterators.

Comment: @teapot418 how should i do that then?

Comment: Why not `strcat(abbreviation, ". ");`?

Comment: what parts should i change ? to what? and why? ty for your answer

Comment: In the future, use proper _const correctness_ to prevent bugs such as this one. Should be `char* abrevia(const char full_name[])`

Answer (score 1):

1. The bus error / segfault is due to passing a read-only string literal to `abrevia()` but `strtok()` modifies it's first argument.  You can pass an array like this:

```
    char *abr = abrevia((char []) { "Artur José Bastos Costa"});
```

or even better if you want to use `strtok()` (opposed to `strpbrk()`) have `abrevia()` copy the string into an array.  This allows you to make the input a pointer to a constant value.

2. `malloc(strlen(full_name))` is 1 byte too small.
3. Prefer passing a variable instead of a type of `sizeof()`.  Less code duplication.  As`sizeof(char)` is defined as 1 so I would just leave it out.
4. Don't cast the `void *` from `malloc()`.
5. You don't do anything with the 2nd middle name.

The basic idea is to handle the first and last token as special cases.  To figure out if it's the last token you need to do 1 token look-ahead:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *abrevia(const char *full_name){
    char *full_name2 = strdup(full_name);
    char *name = strtok(full_name2, " ");
    if(!name) {
        free(full_name2);
        return NULL;
    }
    char *abbreviation = malloc(strlen(full_name2) + 1);
    strcpy(abbreviation, name);
    name = strtok(NULL, " ");
    for(;;) {
        char *name2 = strtok(NULL, " ");
        if(!name2)
            break;
        strcat(abbreviation, " ");
        strncat(abbreviation, name, 1);
        strcat(abbreviation, ".");
        name = name2;
    }
    if(name) {
        strcat(abbreviation, " ");
        strcat(abbreviation, name);
    }
    free(full_name2);
    return abbreviation;
}

int main(){
    char *abr = abrevia("Artur José Bastos Costa");
    printf("%s\n", abr);
    free(abr);
    return 0;
}
```

and here is the output:

```
Artur J. B. Costa
```

Comment: still wont work

Comment: ty, it doesn´t give me the bus error anymore, now i just need to fix the rest